# How to resolve "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException: Reading the request body timed out due to data arriving too slowly"?

Tags: performance, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

While doing API Performance Testing [e.g. No of Threads/Users : 50 with Loop Count : 10], 5 to 8 % samples with POST methods are failing due to below exception :

```
**Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException: Reading the request body timed out due to data arriving too slowly. See MinRequestBodyDataRate.**
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.BadHttpRequestException.Throw(RequestRejectionReason reason)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.Http1MessageBody.PumpAsync()
   at System.IO.Pipelines.PipeCompletion.ThrowLatchedException()
   at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadResult(ReadResult& result)
   at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadAsyncResult()
   at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.DefaultPipeReader.GetResult(Int16 token)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.MessageBody.ReadAsync(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpRequestStream.ReadAsyncInternal(Memory`1 buffer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.FileBufferingReadStream.ReadAsync(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 count, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.WebUtilities.StreamHelperExtensions.DrainAsync(Stream stream, ArrayPool`1 bytePool, Nullable`1 limit, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Formatters.JsonInputFormatter.ReadRequestBodyAsync(InputFormatterContext context, Encoding encoding)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.Binders.BodyModelBinder.BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ParameterBinder.BindModelAsync(ActionContext actionContext, IModelBinder modelBinder, IValueProvider valueProvider, ParameterDescriptor parameter, ModelMetadata metadata, Object value)
```

Could you please suggest how i can fix this ?

**NOTE :I correctly implemented async/await in POST method.This is
    happening to POST method only and out of 500 samples only 20 to
    40 samples are failing per POST method. Providing same inputs while
    testing.**

Comment: What is your hosting model? Kestrel or IIS or HTTP.Sys?

Comment: Do you have a solution for IIS hosting? I am getting same error in iis

Answer (score 4):

You could set`KestrelServerLimits.MinRequestBodyDataRate` property to null in your `Program.cs` as below:

```
.UseKestrel(opt =>
{
    opt.Limits.MinRequestBodyDataRate = null;
});
```

Reference:

[KestrelServerLimits.MinRequestBodyDataRate Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.kestrel.core.kestrelserverlimits.minrequestbodydatarate?view=aspnetcore-3.1#Microsoft_AspNetCore_Server_Kestrel_Core_KestrelServerLimits_MinRequestBodyDataRate)

Comment: hi, is this safe?

Comment: [Seems like this will reopen the door for Slowloris attacks](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/4707#issuecomment-806190211)

Comment: This is a harmful answer

Answer (score 1):

Requests should be resolved fast, and this is a clear warning, that they are not. Exception is, that we are debugging/single-stepping the service, in which case I would prefer more tolerant request limits. In live environments, DDoS and even heavy load can render a system or service unstable very quickly, if limits are too high, because a growing request stack can overwhelm the system.

I made a cache service built on Kestrel and I found two scenarios which could cause this error:

1. The service received a massive amounts of items for a write operation on a quite busy DB table. This happened due to my own poor design. To resolve: either to optimize the update flow or create a per-task based update handler.
2. Service requests have stalled due to an instability, suspension or shut-down. (f.ex. TCP connections may not always shut down immediately using a static HttpClient, it sometimes fails to exit gracefully on shut-down)

*Code below is from a NET 7.0 based kestrel service*

```
// Limits can also be applied within appsettings.json, 
appBuilder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
{
    serverOptions.Limits.MaxConcurrentConnections = 100;
    serverOptions.Limits.MaxConcurrentUpgradedConnections = 100;

#if !DEBUG
    // Live: Demand higher request data-rate limits and low grace period, services can be unreliable.
    // May cause requests to stall resulting in BadHttpRequestException.
    // Catch them in your error handler
    serverOptions.Limits.MinRequestBodyDataRate = new MinDataRate(
        bytesPerSecond: 100,
        gracePeriod: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)
    );
#endif
});
```

Add error handler to app

```
// global error handler
app.UseMiddleware<ErrorHandlerMiddleware>();
```

Error handler:

```
public class ErrorHandlerMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public ErrorHandlerMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next(context);
        }
#if !DEBUG
        catch (Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionResetException)
        {
            // Not of interest - client has ended the connection prematurely. Happens all the time.
            return;
        }
#endif
        catch (BadHttpRequestException bad) when (bad.Message.Contains("data arriving too slowly"))
        {
#if DEBUG
            // The original exception lacks insight.
            throw new BadHttpRequestException($"Request data arriving too slowly: {context.Request.Path}");
#endif
        }
    }
}
```